# Formal MSI support for embedding language transforms into a single MSI

Tags: windows-installer

I have a question regarding embedding transforms (.mst) into a single MSI. I realize this is more of a Microsoft question, but am hoping there are some MSI ninja's here who might be able to help provide an answer.

Question:
Does MSI (Microsoft) formally support embedding language specific transforms (.mst) into a single msi installer? I realize this can be done, but based on my google-foo it's not clear if this is truly proper/supported.

More info:
I'm using a basic MSI project with InstallShield 2012 Spring to produce a single (english based) msi installer. As part of the build I also produce a set of non-english transforms (.mst) which can be applied to the msi using the misexec TRASNFORMS property. However what I really want to do is produce a single msi which embeds the transforms so that I don't need to tote around all the mst files for multi-lang support.

I've used the WiSubStg.vbs and WiLangId.vbs commands to embed the transforms into my msi (post InstallShield/msi build) and things appear to be working. However I'm concerned if this approach is supported/proper. In my searching I found a number of sites which state this approach is not formally supported by MSI, but those posts where years old and I've since seen posts that the MSI technology has made advancements in this area. Moreover I see the Windows dev center discussing embedded transforms formally which leads me to believe the approach supported.

BTW -- My target platform has: Windows ® Installer. V 5.0.9200.16384

Resources:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368347(v=vs.85).aspx
http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/articles/embeddedlang/
http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/multiple-language-setup-package-213354.aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

See: [Multi-Language MSI Packages without Setup.exe Launcher](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/articles/embeddedlang/) (which you listed)

Microsoft does support embedded transforms but what they don't officially support is this technique to get them implicitly applied without the use of a setup.exe to call them out.  While it isn't documented nor thoroughly tested, it has been observed to be implemented by various MSI's that Microsoft product teams have released.

As I understand it, someone will correct me if I'm wrong, this only supports ANSI languages not Unicode languages so a fuller solution would involve using an external UI instead of Windows Installer native UI.